# Within a windows batch file, how do I set an environment variable with the hexadecimal representation of a decimal number?

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables, hex

When using the Windows set /p and set /a commands to accept a hexadecimal value from the command line and convert it to decimal. What I need is to be able to take a decimal value and set and environment variable with its hexadecimal equivalent.

Current batch file coding:

```
@echo off
set HexV1=%1
set HexV2=%2
set /A DecV1=0x%HexV1%
set /A DecV2=0x%HexV2%
set /A HexV3=0x%HexV1% + 0x1
set /A HexV4=0x%Hexv2% + 0x2
set Dec
set Hex
```

Produces:

```
C:>hexmath a f
DecV1=10
DecV2=15
HexV1=a
HexV2=f
HexV3=11
HexV4=17
```

What I need is to be able to set `HexV3` to b and `HexV4` to 11.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

The batch file on channel9 was much to long for my tastes.  Here's a simpler (IMO) version of "tohex.bat" that I just whipped up:

```
@echo off & setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set LOOKUP=0123456789abcdef &set HEXSTR=&set PREFIX=
if "%1"=="" echo 0&goto :EOF
set /a A=%*
if !A! LSS 0 set /a A=0xfffffff + !A! + 1 & set PREFIX=f
:loop
set /a B=!A! %% 16 & set /a A=!A! / 16
set HEXSTR=!LOOKUP:~%B%,1!%HEXSTR%
if %A% GTR 0 goto :loop
echo %PREFIX%%HEXSTR%
```

It works in much the same way as the other script (iteratively dividing by 16), but it uses a string lookup (instead of a series of "if" statements) to build the hex string.  It handles negative numbers as well (two's complement), but it's a bit of a hack.

You could call it from your other batch file like so:

```
for /f "delims=" %%Q IN ('call tohex.bat 0x%HexV1% + 0x1') DO SET HexV3=%%Q
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That string lookup is very neat.

Answer (score 3):

There is an extremely fast and efficient solution at http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeCmdLib.php#toHex. Like the selected answer, it uses a hex map and supports negative numbers. It uses some very clever bit manipulation, and does all looping with a FOR /L statement.

The selected answer is comparatively slow because it relies on a GOTO loop.

Answer (score 1):

[This forum post at channel9.msdn.com](http://channel9.msdn.com/playground/Sandbox/184830/) has a batch script that will convert from integer to hex.

If has a loop using a `GOTO` and processes the number using the modulo - `SET /A` & `%` - and integer division - `SET /A` & `/` - operators and some `IF` statements to build up the hex string.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a great solution from Voodooman at http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2261. It only works up to 32 bit tho :-(
Here's my wrapper script, DecToHex.bat

```
CALL CMD.EXE /C EXIT /B %~1
SET HEXVAL=%=EXITCODE%
SET "%~2=%HEXVAL%"
EXIT /B 0
```

Call it like:

```
>DecToHex.bat 123456 HEXVAL
>ECHO %HEXVAL%
0001E240
```